# Make Bypass with Switches

Tags: switches, bypass

I have the diagram below, but I don't understand how the switches are hooked up. Is that an special switch, or I can achieve that with an special connection? Thank you!

[image: Switch Bypass]

Comment: The dashed line indicates a mechanical coupling between the two parts of the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's two switches connected together that can be in either of two positions. It is a [**DPDT** (double-pole, double-throw)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology) switch.